# Keras model prediction after tensorflow federated learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated

I am working with TensorFlow Federated framework and designed a keras model for a binary classification problem. I defined the iterative process with `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process` and broadcasted the model with
`state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, train_data)`

After the above steps are executed I tried to run the prediction,

```py
    model_test=create_keras_model() # function defining the binary classification model
    model_test.compile(optimizer='adam',            
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    pred_out=model_test.predict(a[0].take(20)) # a[0] is the dataset constructed with the function 
                                             create_tf_dataset_for_client()
    classes =( pred_out >0.5 ).astype("int32")
    np.unique(classes)

    array([[0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0]], dtype=int32)
```

But after applying the tff learning model weights of the state to the model, the prediction is not working as expected. It is showing the same value for all the rows.

```py
    model_test=create_keras_model() # function defining the binary classification model
    state.model.assign_weights_to(model_test)
    pred_out=model_test.predict(a[0].take(20)) # a[0] is the dataset constructed with the function 
                                             create_tf_dataset_for_client()
    print(pred_out)

    array([[-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368],
       [-0.2798368]], dtype=float32)
```

Upon consecutive research, I understood that the the above value '-0.2798368' is the value in state Modelweights

```py
    print(state.model.assign_weights_to(keras_model))
    ModelWeights(trainable=[array([[-4.984627  , -5.193449  , -5.790202  , 
    -5.5200233 , -5.5461893 ,
    -4.977145  , -5.4065394 , -5.619186  , -5.3337646 , -5.136057  ],
    [-0.5657665 , -5.8657775 , -5.3425145 , -5.2261133 , -5.330576  ,
    -5.9684296 , -5.4551187 , -5.3567815 , -4.8706098 , -5.7063856 ],
    [-5.6153154 , -5.9375963 , -5.4587545 , -5.689524  , -5.463484  ,
    -4.9066486 , -5.752383  , -0.3759068 , -5.4120364 , -5.8245053 ],
    [-5.2911777 , -5.42058   , -5.932811  , -5.4922986 , -0.41761395,
    -5.432293  , -5.309703  ,  0.31641293, -5.635701  , -5.7644367 ],
    [ 0.07086992, -5.0122833 , -5.2278    , -5.2102866 , -0.03762579,
    -0.43286362, -4.865974  , -0.3707862 , -5.9437294 , -5.1678157 ],
    [-5.6853213 , -5.467271  , -5.7508802 , -5.4324217 , -5.3518825 ,
    -5.033523  , -4.8834076 , -4.8871975 , -5.9014115 , -5.3266053 ],
    [-5.280035  , -5.763103  , -5.828321  , -5.780304  , -5.908666  ,
    -5.6955295 , -5.6714606 , -4.9686913 , -4.898386  , -5.12075   ],
    [-4.8388877 , -5.7745824 , -5.1134114 , -5.779592  , -5.616187  ,
    -4.870717  , -5.131807  , -5.9274936 , -5.345783  , -5.113287  ]],
    dtype=float32), array([-5.4049463, -5.4049444, -5.404945 , -5.404946 , 
    -5.404945 ,
    -5.4049444, -5.404945 , -5.404945 , -5.4049454, -5.4049444],
    dtype=float32), array([[ 4.972922 ],
    [-4.823935 ],
    [ 4.916144 ],
    [ 5.0096955],
    [-4.9212008],
    [-5.1436653],
    [ 4.8211393],
    [-4.8939514],
    [ 5.1752467],
    [-5.01398  ]], dtype=float32), **array([-0.2798368]**, dtype=float32)], 
    non_trainable=[])
```

1. Do we need to apply the state model weights to the server model explicitly or the tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process api will take care of updating the server model by default? It is given in the tff tutorial that "The aggregate model delta is applied at the server by using the tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer.apply_gradients method of the server optimizer."

Any guidance/suggestions here as where am I going wrong?

Comment: Without knowing `create_keras_model` or `create_tf_dataset_for_client` it will be hard to answer; could these be added to the question? How many rounds of training are run?

Answer (score 1):

We might need to step back a think about how the system models federated computation to understand what is meant by "server model" at one points in time. The `SERVER` and `CLIENTS` concepts exist in a different layer of abstraction that the python runtime the script is executing in. Meaning the code that constructs a Keras model in Python is "outside" the "federated context" that has those notions of placement.

```py
# TFF doesn't know about this model, it doesn't exist at a "placement",
# i.e. it is neither SERVER nor CLIENTS placed.
model = create_keras_model()

learning_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(...)
# During the call to `initialize` a "federated context" exists, which runs
# a `tff.Computation` called `initialize` that creates a value placed at 
# SERVER. However, once the function "returns back to Python", the "state"
# variable we have below no longer has any "placement", its just "in Python".
state = learning_process.initialize()
# When we pass "state" back into the `next` method, it is given placement again
# based on the type signature of `next`. In this case, its placed back at 
# SERVER and the placement is used _during_ the invocation of `next`. Again,
# once `next` returns, the notion of placements goes away; we're back "in 
# Python" without placement.
state, metrics = learning_process.next(state, data)
```

In the code above `model` could be called the "server model", it will initially have the same weights, but it is *not* the `SERVER` placed model referred to in the TFF API documentation. The documentation only refers to values *during* the invocation of a `tff.Computation` (e.g. `initialize` and `next`).

In other words, `model` and `state` are not connected. Updating one will not update the other. To use `model` with newly trained weights (e.g. after a `next` call). The code must assign the `state` weights back to the `model` (as done in the quesiton):

```py
state.model.assign_weights_to(model)
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, I am getting this error `Expected tensorflow_federated.python.learning.model.Model or keras.engine.training.Model, found function.` and I am still not able to see the model prediction. Can you help further?

Comment: Could the rest of the stacktrace be included with the error? Is the error coming from the `assign_weights_to()` call, or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, Dr.Zachary, I just resolved it by doing the following:
`model = create_keras_model()
 state.model.assign_weights_to(model)`
But I don't know how to get the prediction yet, and also, should it be inside the federated computation loop?